# setting an ownership (user_id ) in a db column during the creation of the object via form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(I am sorry if the title is not clear enough)
I am building a rails app that allows users to create tasks and view them. Each user can only see its own tasks. I am using sessions to allow users to login, and skip the login process if they already done so, and using these sessions to find the current user.

Each task should have a title and a body + an owner. The title and the body are inserted by the user via a form, and I want to set the user_id (the owner value) based on the user that is logged in.

I tried to do this through the task controller in the task_params (so the new method will get the current user id, the one that is creating the post). But this does not work.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @tasks = Task.all # need cto hange to get the tasks by owner
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @Task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, current_user.id ,:content)
    end
end
```

The above does not work , because new calls to show

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @task.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= User.find(@task.user_id).name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= @task.content %>
</p>
```

and I am getting the following error

```
  <%= User.find(@note.user_id).name %>
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, task doesn't have a user_id already, or the id is wrong. You need something like

```
<% unless @task.user_id.nil? %>

  <%= User.find(@task.user_id).name %>

<% end %>
```

If you are not sure the id is valid, try

```
<% if user = User.where(id: @task.user_id).first %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller:

```
def create

  @task = Task.new(task_params)

  @task.user_id = session[:current_user_id]
```

Comment: Hey, I understand the problem , but this is not the solution I was looking for. This solution kind of mask the problem. I am trying to figure out how to set the user_id upon creation of the task so I won't have this problem

Comment: When the user logs in, set the user id in the session. In Create, set it from the session before saving.

Comment: I have current_user. and current_user.id will give me the id, I am just not sure where to use it in the creation.